# How to extract a json entry without jq in bash if I know the start and end patterns?

Tags: json, bash

I have a piece of json where I would like to extract a `text` entry string from:

```
{"choices":[{"text":" price for that\n\nSpend full price for that.","index":0,"logprobs":null}],"usage":{"prompt_tokens":13}}
```

I know that the text always starts with `"choices":[{"text":` and ends with `,"index"`. Is there a way I can use native bash tools to extract whatever is in the middle? For the above, I would want to extract `" price for that\n\nSpend full price for that."` as the string. Thanks

Comment: `jq` have no dependencies, why not using the right tool ?

Comment: I am unable to install it into a server I am working off of.

Comment: Is python available on your server?